# Smallest combination in a pencil of quadrics giving an isotropic form

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $A,B$ be integer ternary quadratic forms (in this context, this means that the associated symmetric matrices have integer coefficients) of discriminants $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, say. What is the best possible general bound for integers $u,v$ in terms of $a,b$ with the property that

$$\displaystyle u A - v B$$

is isotropic over $\mathbb{Q}$? That is, we require that the form $Q_{u,v} = uA - vB$ has a rational zero over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: ummm   Did you mean $uA(x,y,z)  - vB(x,y,z)$  as another ternary form?

Comment: @WillJagy yes, that is what I meant

Comment: On what would you allow the bound to depend on?